# Typescript element type definition for obj["any"]

Tags: typescript

In javascript you can do something like this an will work,

```
        let otherVariable = "ww"
        let obj = {
            a:"aa",
            b:"bb",
        }
        obj.a = "aaa";
        obj["c"] = "cc";
        obj["x"] = "xx";
        obj["y"] = "yy";
        obj[otherVariable] = "ww";
```

I would like to do the same in typescript,

```
        let otherVariable = "ww"
        let obj:{a:string, b:string} = {
            a:"aa",
            b:"bb",
        }
        obj.a = "aaa";
        obj["c"] = "cc"; // alert message here
        obj["x"] = "xx"; // alert message here
        obj["y"] = "yy"; // alert message here          
        obj[otherVariable] = "ww"; // alert message here
```

The code will compile and works fine but I get this message,

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ a: string; b: string; }' has no index signature.ts(7017)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is a strongly-typed superset of JavaScript.

Your `object` has type is `{a:string, b:string}`, this mean `obj` only accept `a` and `b` properties.

Redefine type for your `obj`

```
let otherVariable = "ww";
let obj: { [key: string]: string } = {
  a: "aa",
  b: "bb",
};
obj.a = "aaa";
obj["c"] = "cc";
obj["x"] = "xx";
obj["y"] = "yy";
obj[otherVariable] = "ww";
```

Comment: What a easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extend type definition to this one: `{ a: string, b: string, [key: string]: string}`.

By this you will tell Typescript, that your object could have additional key-value pairs with keys of `string` type.